# Invalid ID when inserting

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a visualforce page that displays a list of records as such:
[image]

All of these records are in an object called 'Subjects'. I have a lookup field in an object called 'Exams' linking to 'Subjects'. I'm trying to make a new record in 'Exams' which has an AutoNumber ID and a lookup field for the subject. When I try to insert (in this example Maths) I get the following error:

[image]

which I figured means that the ID 1 doesn't exist in the subjects but i'm trying to add it as a reference into exams. But you can clearly see that ID 1 exists, since I picked it from the list of subjects I dynamically printed on the visualforce page. So now I am not understanding what this error is.

Here is my saveExam method:

```
public PageReference saveExam(){

    Exam__c ex = new Exam__c(Subject__c=subjectIdChosen);
    insert izpit;      

    return null;
}
```

I set the subjectChosenId as such:

```
public String subjectIdChosen {
    get;
    set;
}
```

and the id gets set by the command button:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Choose" rerender="all">             
    <apex:param
       name="examIdParam" 
       value="{!Record.Subject__c}" 
       assignTo="{!subjectIdChosen}" 
    />
</apex:commandButton>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: how `saveExam` is getting called, can you post your VFP and controller code

Comment: What does the Apex debug log tell you when the error occurs? It will be more detailed than the generic error shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Also, your screenshot is showing an error in `{!newExam}` rather than saveExam

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce relates objects via 15 character Id strings that start with 3 characters that tie down the type of the Id. If `Exam__c.Subject__c` is a lookup, it is such an Id that you need to set in the `subjectIdChosen` property (and you should make the type of that property be `Id` so the code is clearer and errors are found earlier). You can keep the Id value in the table rows in a hidden field.

But if `Exam__c.Subject__c` is just a text field, then it should be the string e.g. "Maths".

(Your question prompts some uncertainly because the method you have posted is `saveExam` but the error is for a method `saveIzpit`.)